# Mask RCNN - How to use one JSON File for each image in the dataset?

Tags: computer-vision, python

So I have been using Mask-RCNN for work. I have to do custom object detection. For this I have labelled all my images using either polygon or circle depending on the geometry of the object in the given image. Now I have an annotations folder with separate annotations file for each image. i.e. I have 128 images and hence I have 128 annotations.json files.

But according to the information given on the Mask RCNN github Repo, we need only one annotation json file.

So my question is:

How to change the export_boxes and load_mask functions given in the code to accommodate my problem? If so, how do I do that? Also, consider that that I have 2 shapes in my JSON files. One is Polygon and other is circle. or should I merge all the JSON files into one? If I go ahead with the merging, would that have the correct formatting?

So a part of the JSON file which contains both polygon and circle is given below:

```
{ "label": "anchor", "points": [ [ 35.70270270270271, 18.37837837837838 ], [ 60.56756756756755, 15.675675675675675 ], [ 70.29729729729729, 32.43243243243243 ], [ 59.486486486486484, 49.729729729729726 ], [ 38.40540540540539, 49.729729729729726 ], [ 30.29729729729729, 37.2972972972973 ] ], "group_id": null, "shape_type": "polygon", "flags": {} }, { "label": "anchor", "points": [ [ 244.35135135135135, 168.64864864864865 ], [ 250.2972972972973, 183.78378378378378 ] ], "group_id": null, "shape_type": "circle", "flags": {} }
```

I would like to add something else. I have seen other issues which are related to this problem but I couldn't find any decisive answers and hence I am opening a new question here.

Please help me out.

With regards,
Yash.

Comment: Hi. Programming issues are off-topic here. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details. I will migrate this question to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Okay. I hope I can get some help here.